# tinyscrollbar axis X inside of tinyscrollbar axis Y

Tags: jquery, tinyscrollbar

I have the DIV1 (#scrollbar1) where scrolling is vertical.
And I want to include one DIV2 (#scrollbar2) inside of DIV1 (#scrollbar1) where scrolling is horizontal. Both i use the Tinyscrollbar plugin.

Code ex:

```
<script type="javascript">
     $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar(); /* DIV1 */

     var scr2 = $('#scrollbar2'); /* DIV2 */
     if(src2.length > 0) {
          src2.tinyscrollbar({ axis: x });
     }
     $('#scrollbar2').
</script>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="scrollbar1">     <!-- here is the DIV1 -->
<div class="scrollbar"><div class="thumb"></div></div>
<div class="viewport">
<div class="overview">

     <div id="scrollbar2">     <!-- here is the DIV2 -->
     <div class="scrollbar"><div class="thumb"></div></div>
     <div class="viewport">
     <div class="overview">

          CONTENT 

     </div><!-- .overview -->
     </div><!-- .viewport -->
     </div><!-- #scrollbar2 -->

</div><!-- .overview -->
</div><!-- .viewport -->
</div><!-- #scrollbar1 -->
```

Is this possible ?